# ViewPager: addOnPageChangeListener randomly called after activity recreate

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have `ViewPager` initialized inside `MainActivity`. Its working fine, but as soon as I call `recreate()` on `MainActivity` and activity is "recreated", during initialization my `ViewPager` is bugged and its constantly calling page at index 1 in `addOnPageChangeListener`. Its not called anywhere in code, so I don't understand why its happening. So it switches from first to second tab every second back and forth. I think there is some internal bug if I recreate activity.

```
protected fun createCustomTabScreenFlow(){
        pagerAdapter = FlowViewPagerAdapter(flowList)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = flowList.size

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                backButtonStatus(isEnabled = true)
                App.log("FlowActivity: onPageSelected: $position")
                App.log("FlowActivity: hasVisibleTabs: $hasVisibleTabs")
                if (hasVisibleTabs){
                    val page  = flowList[position]
                    if (page != currentPage){
                        //switch automatically
                        currentPage?.onScreenRemoved()
                        switchScreen(page::class.java)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
        (0..tabLayout.tabCount).forEach { tab->
            flowList.getOrNull(tab)?.icon?.let {
                tabLayout.getTabAt(tab)?.let { tabItem->
                    val tabItemView = CustomResources.inflateLayout(layoutInflater, R.layout.tab_item, null, false) as ViewGroup
                    tabItemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.icon).setImageResource(it)
                    tabItem.customView = tabItemView
                    tabItem.customView?.requestLayout()
                }
            }
        }
        onScreenFlowIntialized()
    }
```

Logs:

```
2022-06-13 12:45:21.098 BaseActivity: onPause
2022-06-13 12:45:21.121 onActivityDestroyed(FlowScreen)
2022-06-13 12:45:21.121 Tab1Screen: onActivityDestroyed
2022-06-13 12:45:21.121 onActivityDestroyed(FlowScreen)
2022-06-13 12:45:21.121 Tab2Screen: onActivityDestroyed
2022-06-13 12:45:21.121 onActivityDestroyed(FlowScreen)
2022-06-13 12:45:21.173 MainActivity: onCreate
2022-06-13 12:45:21.196 BaseActivity: LocationProvider: init
2022-06-13 12:45:21.196 MainActivity: initScreens
2022-06-13 12:45:21.208 MainActivity: onScreenFlowIntialized
2022-06-13 12:45:21.208 FlowActivity: switchScreen: class online.project.tab_main.tabs.MenuScreen
2022-06-13 12:45:21.208 FlowActivity: switchScreen: index: 0
2022-06-13 12:45:21.217 FlowActivity: onPageSelected: 1
2022-06-13 12:45:21.217 FlowActivity: hasVisibleTabs: true
2022-06-13 12:45:21.217 FlowActivity: switchScreen: class online.project.tab_main.tabs.MusicScreen
2022-06-13 12:45:21.217 FlowActivity: switchScreen: index: 1
2022-06-13 12:45:21.219 BaseActivity: onResume
2022-06-13 12:45:21.620 FlowActivity: onPageSelected: 0
2022-06-13 12:45:21.621 FlowActivity: hasVisibleTabs: true
2022-06-13 12:45:21.621 FlowActivity: switchScreen: class online.project.tab_main.tabs.MenuScreen
2022-06-13 12:45:21.621 FlowActivity: switchScreen: index: 0
2022-06-13 12:45:21.621 FlowActivity: switchScreen: page: online.project.tab_main.tabs.MenuScreen
2022-06-13 12:45:21.709 FlowActivity: onPageSelected: 1
2022-06-13 12:45:21.709 FlowActivity: hasVisibleTabs: true
2022-06-13 12:45:21.709 FlowActivity: switchScreen: class online.project.tab_main.tabs.MusicScreen
2022-06-13 12:45:21.709 FlowActivity: switchScreen: index: 1
2022-06-13 12:45:21.709 FlowActivity: switchScreen: page: class online.project.tab_main.tabs.MusicScreen
```

Comment: Where are you calling createCustomTabScreenFlow() function??

Comment: inside onCreate in MainActivity. MainActivity(FlowActivity). MainActivity is extending FlowActitvity. And FlowActivity is extending BaseActivity. FlowActivity is basically used to initialize ViewPager to avoid duplicate code. But this weird bug is happening only if I call .recreate(). I never experienced this in any other cases.